# Can I write the scattering condition in this form?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, scattering, crystals

Consider the elastic scattering of a particle, which can be represneted by a plane wave with wave vector $\mathbf k$, from a periodic potential. We know that $\mathbf{k}$ can be scattered into $\mathbf{k}'$ if
$$\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{G}$$
$$|\mathbf{k}|=|\mathbf{k}'|$$
The first condition is the Laue condition and the second one is the conservation of energy.

---

Given this, Can I assert the following?

> Particle with $\mathbf{k}$ scatter into $\mathbf{k}'$ where
> $$\mathbf{k}'=\frac{|\mathbf{k}|}{|\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}|}(\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G})$$

The above condition follows both the conditions. But It looks like a particle will always going to scatter in some other direction. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Q: But It looks like a particle will always going to scatter in some other direction. Is this correct?

---

Generally, yes if the wave vector $\vec k$ is not ended on the boundary of the first Brillouin zone (1st BZ).

For two points (end points of $\vec k$ and $vec k'$) in a line and both are within the 1st BZ, their connection line is definitely shorter than any reciprocal lattice vector $\vec G$. These two vectors cannot satisfied the Bragg's diffraction condition.

Since The 1st BZ is the Winger cell in the reciprocal lattice: the smallest possible region enclosed by the vertical middle planes of all reciprocal lattice vectors.

But, if the vector $\vec k$ is ended at the boundary of 1st BZ. It is possible to make a back-on scatterring, as shown in the following figure:

$$ \vec k' = -\vec k$$

[image: first brillouin zone]

Comment: In the case of x-ray diffraction, since the momentum of photon is small compared with zone boundary ($\frac{\pi}{a}$), the above condition did not occur.